# Stop or Run a docker container at a given time with a UI

Tags: docker, user-interface, containers, schedule

Do you know a UI, web-based or not (MAC compatible), that allow to stop/run/restart a container on schedule (with container running on local, or not).

For eg:

- stop container XXX at 19/05/2020 1pm
- start container XXX at 19/05/2020 2pm

Everything directly in a UI

I couldn't find anything on the internet

Thanks for your insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/) has a scheduling feature in it, and it's free.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. I've come across it and I think i've misunderstood the definition of Scheduler in the first place. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Would you know something more user friendly (without the need of any code, but just select a container, select a date/time, select action) ?

Comment: @Joseph Sorry, none that I'm personally aware of that are Docker specific, maybe someone else can chime in? However, on Windows we have a built-in app called "Task Scheduler" that can schedule running anything you want; I'm not familiar enough with Macs to know if there's one built-in to it as well, or if you'd have to download one, but it'd be pretty easy to use it to schedule doing the usual `docker run` / `docker stop` commands as needed. =)

Comment: Can't locate this in portainer CE 2.17.1

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but maybe can be helpful to others.
This guide me in the right direction: [Add items to crontab](https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Add_items_to_crontab)

Then, using Putty, I just sent this commands:

```
echo "0 19 * * * docker stop radarr" >> /etc/config/crontab
echo "30 14 * * * docker start radarr" >> /etc/config/crontab
```

To stop radarr at 19:00 and start it at 14:30

Then sent this to wrap it up and restart the cron service:

```
crontab /etc/config/crontab && /etc/init.d/crond.sh restart
```